# Using a WrapPanel/converting from a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

A little new to WPF so forgive me. I need some points here. I currently have a grid that consists of one column of a specific width. In this column, a series of items are created and each has three rows with relevant information within them. So, say I have three items, there will be three blocks (each with three rows).

The code looks something like as follows:

```
<Grid Name="Panel" Margin="0,0,0,45">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="475" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="125" />
        <RowDefinition Height="290" />
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row=0">
        <!--Viewbox contains a grid which contains a textbox with pertinent binding info-->
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row=1">
        <!--Viewbox contains a grid which contains a textbox with pertinent binding info-->
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row=2">
        <!--Viewbox contains a grid which contains a textbox with pertinent binding info-->
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to utilize change this using a WrapPanel so that I can place this panel horizontally and keep the same info? So, for example, have the items look like:

[image]

where the boxes start wrapping after x number of items? And if so, what approach would be recommended?

Quick idea: would it be wise to programmatically add a new column as I progress with each new item, and once I reached my desired x number of items, I can wrap and create a new row of items (each that has its own 3 rows like previously) and match the columns?

Comment: Closed. Why do you ask the same question twice?

Comment: Because no solutions worked. Rather than edit one that will have no traffic, I decided to post some useful information that I've deduced is where I should be focusing. If I was supposed to edit only, I apologize.

Comment: I already told you to use an `ItemsControl`, and you got Sheridan's answer about a `UniformGrid`. How is that "no traffic" ?

Comment: Like I said previously, no solutions worked. Besides, no traffic refers to the present tense, not back when y'all lent some advice. :)

Comment: if "no solutions worked", you should post a comment below Sheridan's answer saying "your solution does not work for me because ..." or reply to my comment about the `ItemsControl` similarly. Posting the same question over and over is not an accepted practice in StackOverflow.

Comment: I understand that. I only asked twice. No harm done. Also, on the other thread - I don't "refuse" a solution. It simply didn't work.

Comment: again if it doesn't work.. you should comment below the answer saying "I tried this and it doesn't work because [...]" asking for further explanations from the person who provided the answer. Ignoring the answer (who somebody took the time to provide, including useful links and stuff) and posting the same question again gives people the impression that you don't care about the time they take to help you out..